# SET RELATION TO FOXPRO

Tags: foxpro

I want to make report in foxpro, with relationship. I have tables "Costumer" and "Order".
Which "Order" table has foreign key "IDCostumer". But i want to show in the Order report the name of costumer instead of "IDCostumer". i hope you understand my question, sorry if my english very bad.

Comment: So? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: the codes :) i don't know how to use set relation to....order data is shown but not the name of costumer

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zkyz3407%28v=vs.80%29.aspx  What exactly isn't clear?

Comment: I write the code: select order->set relation to IDCostumer into Costumer->report form "my/report" preview.....the order data seen but name of costumers not....the field in the report is Costumer.name....how to show the name instead of IDCostumer?

Comment: Do you have **both** tables opened?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68786/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-joni-lelet).

Comment: Show some examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

I got the problem. The problem is the length of data. I make mistake to make table. The length of IDCostumer field is different with the length of Foreign key IDCostumer in order table. that makes data not shown in the report. ok then bye

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer for this website. While you have discovered the answer to your own problem, it does not help anyone else because you haven't actually provided that answer.